# Matrix rotation sort

Tags: code-golf, matrix, sorting

Lets define a non-empty, unsorted and finite matrix with unique numbers as follow:
 $$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 4&5&7\\1&3&6 \end{Bmatrix}$$

Lets define 4 matrix moves as:

- ↑* (up): Moves a column up
- ↓* (down): Moves a column down
- →* (right): Moves a row to the right
- ←* (left): Moves a row to the left

The asterisk(*) represents the column/row that is affected by the move (It can be 0-indexed or 1-indexed. Up to you. Please state which one in your answer).

---

**The challenge** is, using above moves, sort the matrix in a ascendant order (being the top left corner the lowest and the bottom right corner the highest).

**Example**

Input:
$$N=\begin{Bmatrix}4&2&3\\1&5&6 \end{Bmatrix}$$
Possible Output: `↑0` or `↓0`. (Notice any of those moves can sort the matrix so both answer are correct)

---

Input:
$$N=\begin{Bmatrix}2&3&1\\4&5&6 \end{Bmatrix}$$
Possible Output: `→0`

---

Input (Example test case):
 $$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 4&5&7\\1&3&6 \end{Bmatrix}$$
Possible Output: `↑0↑1←1↑2`

---

Input:
$$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 5&9&6\\ 8&2&4\\ 1&7&3 \end{Bmatrix}$$
Possible Output:
`↑0↑2→0→2↑0→2↑1↑2←1`

---

Input:
$$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 6 \\10 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\17 & 7 & 8 & 13 & 9 \\15 & 11 & 12 & 18 & 14 \\26 & 16 & 21 & 19 & 20 \\30 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25  \end{Bmatrix}$$
Possible Output:
`↑2↑1←3→0←3↓0←0←2→3↑3↑4`

---

Input:
$$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 1  \end{Bmatrix} $$
Output:
 or any move

---

Input: 
$$N = \begin{Bmatrix} 1&2\\3&4  \end{Bmatrix} $$
Output:

---

**Notes**

- There can be different correct outputs (there don't need to be necessarily the same as the test cases or the shortest one)
- You can assume it will be always a way to order the matrix
- Edges connects (like pacman :v)
- There wont be a matrix with more than 9 columns or/and rows
- Assume matrix contains only positive non-zero unique integers
- You can use any 4 distinct values other than numbers to represent the moves (in case of that, please state that in your answer)
- Column/row can be 0 or 1 indexed
- Winning criteria [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)

---

Extra test cases are always welcome

Comment: [Here's a website](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/sixteen.html) where you can solve these puzzles yourself.

Comment: @Doorknob That would have been useful when I was writing the challenge Dx. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't think you say anywhere that the solution given has to be as short as possible. Is that intentional? For example is `←0←0` a valid solution for the second example where you have given a solution as `→0`. If it is, I think half of the move options likely won't be used.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes, It doesnt matter how long your solution (output) is as long as it creates the correct result

Comment: Related? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172824/rubik-sorting-a-matrix-a-k-a-the-torus-puzzle

Comment: Will you always be able to perfectly sort it or can you end up with a row like 13 14 16 15?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk You can assume it will be always a way to solve it. I'll add it to the notes

Comment: @Sumner18 Ah, that's the one I was thinking about when I mentioned a similar challenge in the Sandbox! I couldn't find it anymore. :)

Comment: Also some people might want to try https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/580366 made by a youtuber called carykh. It is called "loopover"

Comment: can you use some other encoding for the output?  eg, where each move is mapped to a unique int?

Comment: @Jonah, "*You can use any 4 distinct values other than numbers to represent the moves*".

Comment: I was thinking of encoding row (or col) + direction into a single int, which is not necessarily allowed by the quoted rule

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>226</s>  219 bytes

Brute force search, using *right* (`"R"`) and *down* (`"D"`) moves.

Returns either a string describing the moves, or an empty array if the input matrix is already sorted. Columns and rows in the output are 0-indexed.

```javascript
f=(m,M=2)=>(g=(s,m)=>m[S='some'](p=r=>r[S](x=>p>(p=x)))?!s[M]&&m[0][S]((_,x,a)=>g(s+'D'+x,m.map(([...r],y)=>(r[x]=(m[y+1]||a)[x])&&r)))|m[S]((_,y)=>g(s+'R'+y,m.map(([...r])=>y--?r:[r.pop(),...r]))):o=s)([],m)?o:f(m,M+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY9Na8MwDIbv/RXdJZGJapaPrlvByWWnQTdYjsaM0DWho66DXUYM/e@Z3K6HndbeLEvP80pfzXfj1nbbH2Z787kZx1aAxpXImCihE@BQ00vLWsTO6E2soBdWlFbWCgZR9iXVA2OsunNypaJIy3sVevCBAzaEduCS@DlOBtRcNz2A5JxbhT4EWDkoypM@SdXx2DAqWRRZ8h31r8VfHO9x4v86qONns8oupeW96YHh@ZuxpRGOgVS0fGWWbbgoydi4Nntndhu@Mx281G@v3B3sdt9tWw8tyMl0KgvMMFcYninO8UFNgm7yP0gYpmewuAkM04tLYn4DOMcnmj6Bj7R1cXEs6IBrHen1k5idA3JKOkHjDw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f =                              // f = main recursive function taking:
(m, M = 2) => (                  //   m[] = input matrix; M = maximum length of the solution
  g =                            // g = recursive solver taking:
  (s, m) =>                      //   s = solution, m[] = current matrix
    m[S = 'some'](p =            // we first test whether m[] is sorted
      r =>                       // by iterating on each row
        r[S](x =>                // and each column
          p > (p = x)            // and comparing each cell x with the previous cell p
        )                        //
    ) ?                          // if the matrix is not sorted:
      !s[M] &&                   //   if we haven't reached the maximum length:
      m[0][S]((_, x, a) =>       //     try all 'down' moves:
        g(                       //       do a recursive call:
          s + 'D' + x,           //         append the move to s
          m.map(([...r], y) =>   //         for each row r[] at position y:
            (r[x] =              //           rotate the column x by replacing r[x] with
              (m[y + 1] || a)[x] //           m[y + 1][x] or a[x] for the last row (a = m[0])
            ) && r               //           yield the updated row
      ))) |                      //
      m[S]((_, y) =>             //     try all 'right' moves:
        g(                       //       do a recursive call:
          s + 'R' + y,           //         append the move to s
          m.map(([...r]) =>      //         for each row:
            y-- ?                //           if this is not the row we're looking for:
              r                  //             leave it unchanged
            :                    //           else:
              [r.pop(), ...r]    //             rotate it to the right
      )))                        //
    :                            // else (the matrix is sorted):
      o = s                      //   store the solution in o
)([], m) ?                       // initial call to g(); if we have a solution:
  o                              //   return it
:                                // else:
  f(m, M + 2)                    //   try again with a larger maximum length
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Do you know if there exists an efficient algo for this, or if it's possible to determine  the maximum number of moves a solution can have without brute forcing?

Comment: @Jonah [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220654877_How_to_Solve_the_Torus_Puzzle) is a paper describing a solution and giving an upper bound of the number of moves. (See also [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172824/rubik-sorting-a-matrix-a-k-a-the-torus-puzzle) which is basically the same task with a different winning criterion.)

Comment: Wow, thank you @Arnauld

Answer (score 2):

## <s>[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 296 277 245</s> [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>200</s> 194 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
def f(p):
 s='';u=[]
 while any(ediff1d(p)<0):u+=[(copy(p),s+f'v{v}',f':,{v}')for v in r_[:shape(p)[1]]]+[(p,s+'>0',0)];p,s,i=u.pop(0);exec(f'p[{i}]=roll(p[{i}],1)')
 return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDRbsMgDEWfm6/wm2H1prCmm5Qs/RGEpqoBBSkFRJJuUdVvz0grdS1PvpdzbUOYhta7zTyb6I/gxmOYwB6Dj8NL1mgDhgVeZtDXiNVYS5XBT2s7DXs3Md1YY0STiK@cl@O6luzgw5Q09WuDp/PpgmSwpKXgxkc4gXUQv2XZt/ugEyiFUmotWUgJ3OVIOVdVEmTr8S34wHJe6V99YAaDPNuLqqPvOnarSXDkGUQ9jNFBPy8TYpogpSwI3gk2ijK4HykItgQf6tGVcuEIxDNa/KMruLZbws9MSn0@MOJm32XaYJGLurLF9VKV2SpE6wYWSbumRnjdAfLq5iFLH8YiJ0wvm/8A)

-19: unicode arrows weren't required...
-32: slightly reworked, but much slower performance on average.
-45: took some inspiration from @Arnauld's answer. Switched to Python 3 for `f''` (-4 bytes)
-6: [`range( )`→`r_[: ]`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156676/81203), `diff(ravel( ))`→`ediff1d( )`

---

Exhaustively searches combinations of all possible `↓` moves and `→0`. Times out on the third test case.

Since `→n` is equivalent to

```python
↓0↓1...↓(c-1) 	... repeated r-n times
→0
↓0↓1...↓(c-1)	... repeated n times
```

where `r` and `c` are the numbers of rows and columns, these moves are sufficient to find every solution.

---

```python
from numpy import*
def f(p):
    s=''                                    #s: sequence of moves, as string
    u=[]                                    #u: queue of states to check
    while any(ediff1d(p)<0):                #while p is not sorted
        u+=[(copy(p),s+f'v{v}',f':,{v}')    #add p,↓v to queue
            for v in r_[:shape(p)[1]]]      # for all 0<=v<#columns
        u+=[(p,s+'>0',0)]                   #add p,→0
        p,s,i=u.pop(0)                      #get the first item of queue
        exec(f'p[{i}]=roll(p[{i}],1)')      #transform it
    return s                                #return the moves taken
```

---

`>v` correspond respectively to `→↓`. (others undefined)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
ṙ€LXȮƊ¦1
ÇZÇZƊ⁾ULXȮOịØ.¤?F⁻Ṣ$$¿,“”Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzpmPmtb4RJxYd6zr0DJDrsPtUUB0rOtR475QkKj/w93dh2foHVpi7/aocffDnYtUVA7t13nUMOdRw9yHO1f9//8/2lTHUscsVifaQsdIxyQWAA)

Full program. Outputs moves to STDOUT using L for left and R for right. Keeps trying random moves until the matrix is sorted, so not very efficient in terms of speed or algorithmic complexity.